# Open other file extensions in org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I make Emacs open other file extensions than `.org` with the Emacs org mode? I have an editor on the iPad that is not able to handle `.org` files, so I'd like to use e.g. `.text` with org mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a duplicate, but the answer is easy enough:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.text\\'" . org-mode))
```

Comment: Nitpick: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.text\\'" . org-mode))` [will only match `.text` at the end of the file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494402/setting-auto-mode-alist-in-emacs)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line at the beginning of your .text file:

```
#    -*- mode: org -*-
```

You can also use this for .org_archive files

I know this question is old, but I think it is slightly easier and works, as far as I know, for all text-like files.