# emacs makefile-mode for Makefile.include

Tags: emacs, makefile

I use file named Makefile.include as a GNU makefile. I am trying to get emacs use the makefile-mode to use for this file. Alt-X makefile-mode works. Is there a way to tell emacs to use this major mode for this file right after opening automatically?

I tried putting

```
# _*_ mode: makefile; _*_
```

in the file but that does not appear to have the right effect. Btw I could not find the list of allowed strings one can use after mode:, so I tried BDSmakefile and some other variations as well.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting auto-mode-alist in emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494402/setting-auto-mode-alist-in-emacs)

Comment: `-`(dash) should be used instead of `_` underscore. so you should write like `# -*- mode: makefile -*-`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs change file extension - mode association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941995/emacs-change-file-extension-mode-association)

Answer (score 2):

See this question: [Setting auto-mode-alist in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494402/setting-auto-mode-alist-in-emacs), and use the pair `("Makefile\\.include\\'" . makefile-mode)`.

Comment: I was interested in putting this in the file itself and not in the emacs config. syohex is right I had a typo...